# Bootstrap Ellipsis in list-group is resulting into overwritten rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code with ellipsis

```
<div class="list-group" id="NotificationList">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="notificat" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">This is your first notification. This is your first notification. This is your first notification. This is your first notification.
                            </span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="notificat" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}

.notificat {
  max-width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SimplytheVinay/fqfmh818/1/

Here is another one without ellipsis, which is working as per my expectation.

```
<div class="list-group" id="NotificationList">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
    <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/SimplytheVinay/mp97gLjm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing display of `notificat` class to `inline-block` then there is no need to floating left.

```
.notificat {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

```css
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}

.notificat {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-group-item{
  padding: 9px 15px !important; /* adjust padding from 10px to 9px to keep same list view after adding Ellipsis */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="NotificationList">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notificationModal" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            </label>
        </div>
        <span class="">This is your first notification.</span>
        <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
    </a>
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="This is your first notification." class="list-group-item">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            </label>
        </div>
        <span class="notificat" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">This is your first notification. This is your first notification. This is your first notification. This is your first notification.
        </span>
        <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            </label>
        </div>
        <span class="notificat" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">This is your first notification.</span>
        <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Adding display: inline-block; solves the problem. One more thing, why are we changing padding ? Does ellipsis changes the padding around elements ?

Comment: @Crawling You're welcome, glad to help you. changing padding is optional but _display: inline-block;_ causing changes of view. nevermind! you can change padding values and see how the view is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove " float: left; " this class " .notificat "

Remove this:

```
.notificat {
  float: left;
}
```

See [Updated Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fqfmh818/4/)

Comment: Yes, It solves the overwriting issue. But Ellipsis doesn't work with this. adding display: inline-block; solves the issue.